# Can't find Report studio in IBM Cognos Analytics

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have access to IBM Cognos Analytics (Modeller and Developer level ) in my organisation. I don't see these three studios (Analysis, Event, Query) inside the System Views - Ad Hoc environment. Pls help.

I have tried google and IBM websites but to no solution

not sure if there is a code to this problem.

I expect to see these studios.

Comment: Probably because the original post claims that web searches were performed.  When I search for "cognos analytics create report" on google.com, every link on the first page of results appears to provide good information.  If there is a more specific problem, like the "New" button does not appear in the left nav bar, that should have been stated.  Also, "modeler and developer" is vague since using roles is only one way to set capabilities and permissions in Cognos.  This appears to be a question for the administrator of that specific system, not the community.

Comment: What is the "System Views - Ad Hoc environment"?  I have never heard of that.

Comment: Ad hoc environment does that mean Query Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event Studio, Analysis and Query studio only work in Internet Explorer, not in Chrome, Firefox etc.They are located under "+"  then "Other"

Answer (score 1):

Reporting: to create a new report, in the Welcome portal, tap New icon (plus sign), then tap Report. For a report entry in a content list, if you tap tap the More icon, then tap Edit, the report opens in Reporting.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.wig_cr.doc/c_gtstd_map_functionality.html

To enable legacy studios
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21986776

Answer (score 0):

Ask your Cognos Analytics Administrator.

Comment: Now, this is a useful answer

Comment: It sounds like a permissions thing, not something that can be coded around.